# Object goes back to Initial Position after 4 rotations

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a solar system in OpenGL/C++ and my planets keep restarting from their initial position after 4 rotations around the sun and I can't figure out why.

I believe it has something to do with the DayOfYear variable that is making it restart, but I have tried altering it and haven't had any success, so I'm hoping someone can help me out here. So my question is, why are my planets going back to their initial positions after 4 rotations and how can I stop this?

Below is my main drawing function:

```
static void Animate(void)
{
    // Clear the redering window
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (spinMode) {
        // Update the animation state
        HourOfDay += AnimateIncrement;
        DayOfYear += AnimateIncrement/24.0;

        HourOfDay = HourOfDay - ((int)(HourOfDay/24))*24;
        DayOfYear = DayOfYear - ((int)(DayOfYear/365))*365;
    }

    // Clear the current matrix (Modelview)
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Back off eight units to be able to view from the origin.
    glTranslatef ( 0.0, 0.0, -40.0 );

    // Rotate the plane of the elliptic
    // (rotate the model's plane about the x axis by fifteen degrees)
    glRotatef( 15.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );

    // Draw the sun -- as a yellow, wireframe sphere
    glColor3f( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
    glutWireSphere( 4.0, 15, 15 );

    /*
     |
     | MERCURY
     |
     */
    glPushMatrix();
    // Draw the Earth
    // First position it around the sun
    //      Use DayOfYear to determine its position
    glRotatef( 360.0*DayOfYear/88.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
    glTranslatef( 6, 0.0, 0.0 );
    // Save matrix state
    // Second, rotate the earth on its axis.
    //      Use HourOfDay to determine its rotation.
    glRotatef( 360.0*HourOfDay/24.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
    // Third, draw the earth as a wireframe sphere.
    glColor3ub(255,255,255);
    glutWireSphere( 0.1, 10, 10);
    glPopMatrix();



    // Flush the pipeline, and swap the buffers
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();

    glutPostRedisplay();        // Request a re-draw for animation purposes

}
```

Comment: What are the types of `HourOfDay `, `DayOfYear` and `AnimateIncrement`? How do you calculate the value of `AnimateIncrement`? And finale, it's seems me that in `HourOfDay = HourOfDay - ((int)(HourOfDay/24))*24;` should be `HourOfDay = HourOfDay % 24;`. Same to `DayOfYear`

Comment: @Amadeus sorry should have included this. They are all floats. HourOfDay and DayofYear are set to 0 when declared and AnimateIncrement is set to 24.0 when declared. Assume AnimateIncrement stays at 24.0

Comment: What do you intend to achieve with: `HourOfDay = HourOfDay - ((int)(HourOfDay/24))*24;`? If `AnimateIncrement  = 24.0`, this means that `HourOfDay = 24` (from the previous statement), so this calculation makes `HourOfDay = 0` or near zero. I suggest you to pass your program through a debugger to see if these values (`HourOfDay` and `DayOfYear`) are what are you expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well well I guess if you are trying to make an orbit with days
and rotating the earth according the hour.

well here you try to add to HourOfDay el número de horas que han pasado son 24 this is fine.

```
HourOfDay  + =  AnimateIncrement; 
DayOfYear   + =  AnimateIncrement / 24.0;
```

remove it always return zero.

```
HourOfDay  =  HourOfDay  -  ((int) (HourOfDay / 24)) * 24; 
DayOfYear   =  DayOfYear   -  ((int) (DayOfYear  / 365)) * 365;
```

Well, This line does not make much sense for the division of 88.

```
glRotatef(360.0*DayOfYear/88, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
```

divide it per 356.

```
glRotatef(360.0*DayOfYear/365, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
```